# Is System.ServiceModel.Web.dll the obsoleted WCF Web API?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm new to the WCF and Web API technology. I quite like the WCF programming model while my major client app is in JavaScript. So my nature choice is WCF Web API. However on WCF Web API CodePlex page, it says WCF Web API is obsoleted. I understand the WCF Web API was NuGet package but maybe now it's released in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll. So which part on earth is no longer supported by MS, the NuGet package or the .net assembly? There is no .net (even v4.5) document saying the .net assembly is obsoleted or out of support, so should we stop using the WCF Web API for future proof or not? Please advise.

Thanks.

Wayne

Answer (score 2):

WCF WebAPI has been replaced by [ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

More details can be found in [this announcement](https://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/319671) on the WCF codeplex site:

> For several years now the WCF team has been working on adding support for REST. This resulted in several flavors of REST support in WCF: WCF WebHTTP, WCF REST Starter Kit, and then finally **WCF Web API**. In parallel the ASP.NET MVC team shipped support for building basic web APIs by returning JSON data from a controller. *Having multiple ways to do REST at Microsoft was confusing* and forced our customers to choose between two partial solutions. 
>   [...] The WCF and ASP.NET teams were merged together and tasked with creating a single integrated web API framework. The result is ASP.NET Web API.

Emphasis mine.

That announcement details what this means for WCF Web API:

> ASP.NET Web API is effectively the next version of WCF Web API. There will not be a separate release for WCF Web API and **we will retire all WCF Web API content by the end of the year**<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: That is the end of 2012 and obviously long past.</sup>

Again, emphasis mine.

That is the official statement that deprecates the WCF Web API. It would be a bad idea to start using it now.